# Pair in sorted Array

Tags: arrays, sorting, max

How to make pairs of a sorted array such that the addition on the pairs after by multiplying of a pair is highest?
for example:
input array A[6,3,2,5]
output: (6 * 5)+(3 * 2)=36

Comment: Are you using a specific programming language? And how long are your arrays typically?

Comment: let's say I'm using java and the length of the array depends on the user, i.e. N

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve maximum product by multiplying the first two largest numbers. In the example you have given, A[6, 3, 2, 5]. The two largest number are 6 and 5. Therefore the maximum product that can be achieved by picking any two numbers from the array is 6*5 = 30.

I can help more if you may give more examples and show how to do the pairing in inputs of larger size. Describe your question a bit more.